# Wrong output json_encode PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using this code to build an array and encode it to JSON.

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

   $results[] = array(
      'wdatatype' => $row['wdatatype'],
      'wdb' => $row['wdb'],
      'wbyte' => $row['wbyte'],
      'wbit' => $row['wbit'],
      'bitval' => $row['bitval'],     
   );

   }
       $json = json_encode($results);
       echo $json;
```

The output is this

```
     [{"wdatatype":"DB","wdb":"100","wbyte":"0","wbit":"0","bitval":"1"}]
```

But for my jQuery script I need the output to be

```
     {"wdatatype":"DB","wdb":"100","wbyte":"0","wbit":"0","bitval":"1"}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: What should output look like if you have more than one row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're problem seems to stem from the fact that you're creating a multi-dimensional array. You're pushing an array as an element of the existing `$results` array. For you're desired output, `$results` should be an associative array, **not** an array of associative arrays.

Provided there is only one row in your result set, try this instead:

```
// Remove the while loop if you're only returning a single row
// such as with a LIMIT = 1 clause in your SQL statement.
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

// Push the single row as an array into $result
$results = array(
    'wdatatype' => $row['wdatatype'],
    'wdb' => $row['wdb'],
    'wbyte' => $row['wbyte'],
    'wbit' => $row['wbit'],
    'bitval' => $row['bitval'],     
 );

// Now echo the json_encode
echo json_encode($results);
```

When converted using `json_encode`, the above will turn into a single object like so:

```
{"wdatatype":"DB","wdb":"100","wbyte":"0","wbit":"0","bitval":"1"}
```

rather than an array of objects.

**Note:** As *@PankajGarg* and *@AmalMurali* pointed out this should be used if you're ***only*** returning a single row. Failing to remove the while loop and returning a result set of more than one row will yield you a return of the ***last*** row only.

For a result set containing multiple rows, your current structure will work perfectly.

Alternatively as *@Nilpo* pointed out, you can simplify the above process by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to return an associative array for you.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

// Now echo the json_encode
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: What if there is more than one row ?

Comment: Wow! it was that easy? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be noted that, if the multiple rows are returned, the JSON representation would only contain the last row. If you want the first row instead, add a `break` statement inside the loop. Or simply remove the `while` loop.

Comment: @PankajGarg and _@AmalMurali_ make a valid point. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Otherwise If you want for each row to print a JSON as you want, you will need to iterate the result array.

Comment: @AmalMurali You made a very valid point. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PankajGarg Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Since all of your columns names are the same, why not just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and skip all of this?

Comment: @Nilpo Also a valid point. That's a good question for the OP. Then you could simply `return json_encode($row);`. Mind if I add that to the answer above?

Comment: @Nilpo Thanks for the feedback/edit. I've added your name for credit.

Comment: There is one problem with `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);` If I use this it will return all columns in my table, however there are 2 columns I want to exclude from the object.

Comment: @Bavilo Ah, well that makes sense then. In that case, stick with the first code block. It should solve your problem. Optionally, edit your SQL statement to return only the desired columns, especially if you don't need the others. No use in wasting the processing cycles or bandwidth on unused data.

Comment: I need the other columns as well, just not in that object, the other columns are used to make checks.

Comment: @Bavilo Ok. Fair enough. In that case, the first example should work for you.